# uploading files in webviewapp in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, upload

This is my code for the webview app, and I also gave permission for the camera and also it has in the android manifest. I also give permissions in the mic, and audio because I also see it as the problem.

My logs shows: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

````
  final Uri uri = EnvData.webUrl.contains("maya")
      ? Uri.parse("https://${EnvData.webUrl}?email=${widget.email}")
      : Uri.parse("https://${EnvData.webUrl}");

  final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params =
      WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform
          ? WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
              allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
              mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{})
          : const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

  final controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(
    params,
    onPermissionRequest: (WebViewPermissionRequest request) => request.grant(),
  )
    ..clearCache()
    ..clearLocalStorage()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0xFFFFFFFF))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
          setState(() {
            progressValue = progress.toDouble();
          });
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
            _launchURL(Uri.parse(request.url));
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          } else if (request.url.contains("tel:")) {
            _launchURL(Uri.parse(request.url));
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(uri);

  return controller;
}```
````